# Embedding a web link into a listview text using WinRT

Tags: listview, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

Is it possible to embed a link, e.g.: http://www.sun.com into a listview, so that this link becomes sensitive?  I was under the impression that just including a "http://" would do the trick (like a WebView control), but it doesn't seem to.

I want to be able to display a link that launches an external browser when clicked.

Answer (score 1):

you can add `HyperlinkButton` to `ListBox` for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event handler like PointerEntered and PointerExited to change some property of element when the pointer is over the link like Foreground to change the color.